# I would like to have a TapBar in the center of the scaffold

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Is it possible to have a TapBar in the center of the scaffold, like in a Column, instead of the AppBar, I tried many things but nothing worked, sorry if my English isn't that well. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

This code works, and it is pretty straightforward.

```dart
class Main extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: DefaultTabController(
        length: 3,
        child: Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
          body: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
            children: [
              Flexible(
                child: TabBar(
                  tabs: [
                    Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_car)),
                    Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_transit)),
                    Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_bike)),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Flexible(
                child: TabBarView(
                  children: [
                    Icon(Icons.directions_car),
                    Icon(Icons.directions_transit),
                    Icon(Icons.directions_bike),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Sorry but do i have to do something in particular to implement it? Beacuse using the tabbarview and switching between screens it gives me some errors, thanks again for the help

Comment: I'll update and add the implementation of using screens to the code.

Answer (score 0):

use toggle button with rotatedbox for vertical tabbar, [example](https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-widget-in-focus-togglebuttons-know-it-all-b0f0c23f4518)